# defining different cases for function im matlab (symfun)

Tags: matlab

i want to create a function (symfun), and i want to divide it to cases, i.e if t> then then answer will be a and if t<0 the answer will be b. 
the thing is, that matlab wont allow me to put an if statements after a sym function.

```
>> l = symfun(0, [m]);
>> l(m) = if m>0 3
```

also i tried to create a function:

```
function [x1] = xt_otot_q3(t)
```

and tried to connect between the two functions:

```
>> l(m) = xt_otot_q3(m)
Conversion to logical from sym is not possible.
```

is there any way to break a symfun into cases?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand what you want.
This code 'combines' the functions symfun and xt+otot_q3 defined below:

```
function test; 
  m=randn(4);               % N(0,1) random numbers
  l=xtotot_q3(symfun(0,m))  % combine xt_otot_q3 and symfun 
  l=symfun(0,xtotot_q3(m))  % combine symfun and xt_otot_q3
return

function lval=symfun(thr,rval); 
  lval=ones(size(rval));    % output, size of input, = 1 
  lval(rval<thr)=-1;        % output = -1 if input < thr 
return

function lval=xtotot_q3(rval); 
  lval=3*rval+1;            % some function, in this case 3 * input + 1 
return
```

You can save the whole bit as test.m and then call `test` from the matlab prompt. Maybe if you start with this then you can modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: hi, i did save it and ran it, the problem is that i dont get any function after i run it... i mean there is no lval that i can evaluate... do you know why is that?

Comment: you can change the 1st line to `function l=test;` -- if you then type `test` in matlab, the second `l` is returned as `ans`. Or if you type `l=test` it is returned as `l`.

Comment: And, if you want the first `l` rather than the second, you can change the order of the two lines starting with `l=...`